# install Munin on rhel4-32

Tags: installation, munin

```
# cat /proc/version
> Linux version 2.6.9-023stab048.6-enterprise (root@rhel4-32) (gcc version 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2)) #1 SMP Mon Nov 17 19:09:18 MSK 2008
```

This is Redhat4, right? and i do not have yum?

http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/LinuxInstallation do not work at all.

Thx in advance

Answer (score 1):

By "i do not have yum" I'm assuming you mean that you do not have munin / munin-node available in an installed yum repository. That is true by default. I would suggest installing the EPEL repository.

I have directions for installing it here (you'll just need to change your URLs for RHEL4 as below):

http://ridingthecloud.com/installing-epel-repository-centos-rhel/

**Install RHEL4 EPEL on 32-bit Systems:**

`sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/i386/epel-release-4-9.noarch.rpm`

**Install RHEL4 EPEL on 64-bit Systems:**

`sudo rpm -Uvh http://download.fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/4/x86_64/epel-release-4-9.noarch.rpm`

Once you have installed the new repository you should be able to install Munin via yum pretty easily. The command should just be:

`yum install munin munin-node`

More details here:

http://ridingthecloud.com/linux-server-performance-monitoring-munin/